# How to convert in HTML table specific text valule into a href link (<a> tag) by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, tags, href

On the homepage of my Flask application, I have an HTML table whose last column values can be text which can be schematized as follows:
[image]

I am now trying to use Javascript to convert all the "Edit Issue" values in the HTML table by an href link that would allow me once I click on this link to access another HTML page. For doing this, I loop every row in the HTML table and put HTML link inside cell. Unfortunately, when I run the code below, I get a source map error:

Please find below my JS code:

```
function convert_cellTable(){
let table=document.getElementsByTagName("table").value;
let row, rows = table.rows;
let cell, cells;

// For each row in the table
for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  row = rows[i];
  cells = row.cells;

// Identify in each cell if the text content equal to "Edit Issue"
for (var j=0, jLen=cells.length; j<jLen; j++) {
  cell = cells[j];
  let TextToConvert = "Edit Issue"
  if (cells[j].textContent == TextToConvert) {
      // cell text is replaced by an HTML link
      cell[j].innerHTML = "<a href='updateform.html'>Edit Issue</a>";
  }
 }
 }
}
```

Could you please provide me guidelines to correct the code above. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through it?

Comment: No, what do you mean by this ?

Comment: Loop rows and put html inside cell by row.

Comment: Here is a link to how to use the debugger in chrome. All web browsers have debuggers that work almost exactly the same, and most open with F12 (safari is different): https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of columns is known or is fixed, you could select all of the last column `td` elements, then loop through those to update the `innerHTML` accordingly.

```js
const lastColumnCells = document.querySelectorAll('table td:nth-child(5)'); // Assuming column 5 of table

lastColumnCells.forEach(cell => {
  if (cell.innerText === 'Edit Issue') {
    cell.innerHTML = '<a href="updateform.html">Edit Issue</a>';
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
    <th>Header3</th>
    <th>Header4</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Edit Issue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Edit Issue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Edit Issue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, it's working perfectly now